# System Access Denied Unable to Delete Folder

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to delete a folder on my D:\ drive. I tried tried everything up till loading myself as the system account in a CMD see below.

```
D:\>takeown /F torrent
ERROR: Access is denied.
D:\>whoami
nt authority\system
D:\>
```

Unedited from my CMD Window.

Comment: You have your solution [here](http://superuser.com/a/321475/270195)

Comment: "I tried everything...".  Please tell us exactly what you tried already.  I.E.:  did you try a CHKDSK and a reboot yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like there's something on your system that is still accessing something in that directory.  I'd use a tool like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to search for any open "file handles" on the `D:\torrent` directory, and kill the processes which own those handles.  You should then be able to delete the directory.

Comment: uTorrent had a handle on the folder. Weird :/ Thanks Anyway.

Comment: ... and you check the proces explorer by running `resmon.exe` from the command line or from the Run dialog ...